# Replace XML element with text wrapped in CDATA using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to replace some text in an XML element with new text which I need to wrap in CDATA.

```
asset = request.responseXML;
asset.getElementByTagName("url").textContent = newUrl;
```

`newUrl` needs to be wrapped in CDATA since it can contains special characters. How is this possible? I have tried the following but it doesn't work

```
asset.getElementByTagName("url").textContent = "<![CDATA[" + newUrl + "]]>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you change `textContent` which strips tags. Correct syntax is

```
var newUrl='/some/url?id=123&user=joe+dow';
var asset = request.responseXML; //xml Document
var urls = asset.getElementByTagName("url"); //HTMLCollection
urls[0].innerHTML= '<![CDATA[' + newUrl + ']]>';
console.log(asset.documentElement.outerHTML); //test it
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is take the innerHTML of your element and reset it using textContent.

```js
var xmlString = "<root><foo /><bar /><url><a href='http://stackoverflow.com/'>foo</a></url></root>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
var urlTag = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("url")[0];
urlTag.textContent = "<![CDATA[" + urlTag.innerHTML + "]]>";

console.log(urlTag.textContent);
```